# Overlaying a mbtiles tile layer produced with tilemill over another layer maintaining transperency

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, tilemill, transparency-opacity, tilestache

So using leaflet, I'm overlaying my base tile layer as google satellite imagery. I want to overlay another layer (Mbtiles layer) produced with tilemill over this satellite layer. I was successful in doing this. I set the background of the mbtiles file as transparent on tilemill. Im using tilestache to serve the tiles and leaflet for a JS API.

Now, I want this mbtiles layer to only show the coloured layers (roads, polygons etc.) and the background to be transparent (to show the google satellite layer wherever the mbtiles layer is transparent). But this is not happening. The background of the MBtiles layer is white and there is no transparency. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: what format are your tiles in? Tiff/PNG there is a bug; https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1416

Comment: Is the background of your map in TileMill definitely transparent? Ie, there should not be a `map { background:white; }` line.